# can someone please tell me why $(this).attr('id') not working

Tags: jquery, laravel

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var receiver_id = '';
    var my_id = "{{ Auth::id() }}";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.user').click(function(){
            $('.user').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        
            receiver_id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(receiver_id);
        });
    });     
</script>
```

I'm trying to get the ID of the user when the button is clicked but it keeps giving me an error saying it is `undefined`.

Comment: Does the `.user` element have any `id`? We're not seeing that tag in your code.

Comment: yes the user has got an id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me.

```js
var receiver_id = '';
var my_id = "{{ Auth::id() }}";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.user').click(function() {
    $('.user').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    receiver_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(receiver_id);
  });
});
```

```css
li.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="user" id="Tom">Tom</li>
  <li class="user" id="Robert">Robert</li>
  <li class="user" id="Joe">Joe</li>
  <li class="user" id="Frank">Frank</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var receiver_id = '';
      var my_id = "{{ Auth::id() }}";
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.user').click(function(){
          $('.user').removeClass('active');
          $(this).attr('id', 'active');
    
          receiver_id = $(this).attr('id');
          alert(receiver_id);
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="user">User</div>
```

Attribute is not classname, what you are trying to do is to add class active to the DOM element. To set an attribute use line 10 in the below snippet.